# Keeping same name for docker cp command use

Tags: linux, docker

I want to be able to restart a docker but get it to have the same name/label each time, so when I reboot my linux server I can run a "docker cp " command without having to run some special script to get the container ID of the current version of that particular docker image.

Can someone please suggest how I could do this please?

Comment: Use docker-compose to set up your containers, there you can specify the name and also all other options. It's also easily versioned in any VCS, if you care about such things. Or just use `--name` to specify it on the `docker run` command line.

Comment: You should rarely need `docker cp`, and it probably shouldn't be something you need to script.  Can you avoid this, maybe by building the file into your image or via a volume mount?

Comment: Agree with @DavidMaze - this sounds like an X/Y problem. Docker CP should only ever be needed for debugging, if you're scripting it, you're doing something wrong

Comment: the docker cp is to transfer a file into the docker from the host linux OS, so the docker can then process the file. The alternative is to run a python script inside the docker that then requires a connection out of the docker to the host OS to access services - in this case, is the preferred option to do everything from within docker?

Comment: @steve: [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) are usually used to make files on the host accessible to the container. For example you can use `docker run -v /host/path/filename:/container/path/filename:ro ...` to make the file accessible to the container in a read-only way.

Comment: @steve, why? I'm genuinely asking. Half the point of containers is their ephemerality. It seems to me very counter-intuitive. Can you explain what you're trying to achieve with this?

Comment: Its a dev visual system. We run python on linux docker host to connect to and take a photo via an external TCPIP connected host, pull photo back to local linux host disk, then copy it into the docker to run thru an AI image classifier. Then drop it back to the host so can view it ( cant look at jpg images inside docker ). We just had to get something up and going quickly, happy to look at other ways to do this. One of my concerns is whether we can run python code in docker to connect to the external IP address ( i.e. outside of the docker host ). We currently run the python code on linux host.

Answer (score -1):

```bash
docker run --name=your_container_name ...
```